Ubuntu 20.04 juju deploy now openstack service are waiting or blocked
I am a new Ubuntu 20.04 user.
ubuntu 20.04 + maas 3.2.11 + juju 2.9.50 + lxd 5.0.3 + openstack ussuri
using openstack base #79 charm， “series: focal” and “source cloud:focal-ussuri”  were set in bundle.xml
After juju deploy，I found that almost all openstack service are waiting or blocked or error，especially lxd container
Then I checked the logs：
ubuntu@controller:/var/log/juju$ cat machine-0.log
2024-08-27 14:04:35 ERROR juju.worker.dependency engine.go:695 "lxd-container-provisioner" manifold worker returned unexpected error: container types
2024-08-27 14:04:35 ERROR juju.worker.dependency engine.go:695 "kvm-container-provisioner" manifold worker returned unexpected error: container types
2024-08-27 14:04:35 ERROR juju.worker.dependency engine.go:695 "broker-tracker" manifold worker returned unexpected error: no container types determined

2024-08-27 14:17:40 INFO juju.packaging.manager run.go:88 Running: snap info lxd
2024-08-27 14:18:11 INFO juju.container.lxd initialisation_linux.go:300 switching LXD snap channel from 4.0/stable/ubuntu-20.04 to 5.0/stable
2024-08-27 14:18:11 INFO juju.packaging.manager run.go:88 Running: snap refresh --channel 5.0/stable lxd
2024-08-27 14:18:34 ERROR juju.packaging.manager run.go:144 packaging command failed: exit status 1; cmd: "snap refresh --channel 5.0/stable lxd"; output: error: cannot refresh "lxd": persistent network error: Post
       "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": dial tcp: lookup
       api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution

2024-08-27 14:18:34 ERROR juju.worker.dependency engine.go:695 "lxd-container-provisioner" manifold worker returned unexpected error: setting up container dependencies on host machine: packaging command failed: exit status 1

snap info lxd shows already installed lxd version 5.0.3，why logs keep switch lxd form 4.0/stable to 5.0/stable？
With all these openstack services that have failed（especially lxd container) how can I fix this？
Pictures below :




Please do not post pictures of text. Cut and paste text into the body of the question. Pictures can not be sized scrolled or sorted and often force opening another window to read them.
